# What is the best practice for creating hundreds of objects?

Tags: ios

I'd like to create an App with categories. Each category should own an array of activities which have the properties title and score.

Do I have to create all these activity objects like this?:

```
Activity activity1* = [[Activity alloc] initWithTitle: @"Bla" andScore: 2];
Activity activity2* = [[Activity alloc] initWithTitle: @"Blub" andScore: 1];
Activity activity3* = [[Activity alloc] initWithTitle: @"Bla" andScore: 4];
...
```

...or is there an other option? I guess it will take a lot of time doing it like this.

Here are more details:

category object (I need 20 of those),
properties: title, activity array

activity object (for each category object I'd like to create hundreds of activity objects),
properties: title, score (from 1 to 100)

If I use a for loop I'd have to assign the score of theses activities afterwards.

I have now created macros which simplify the coding:

```
// for creating a category
    #define K(string, array) [[Kategorie alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString((string), nil) andActivityArray: (array)] 
// for creating an activiy
    #define A(string, score) [[Activity alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString((string), nil) andScore:(score)]
```

Comment: That's what foreach's are for. Isn't there a way to use those? Could you give some more context to your development situation?

Comment: you need two ordered array one with the title the other with the score  and make a i=0 while (i < [onOfYourArray count]){ code...; i++;}

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` or a `while` loop for this. You could have the data in a plist or in a text file and enumerate over the lines in the text file with a for loop.

**Edit:**

Maybe this [Link](http://iosdevelopertips.com/data-file-management/reading-a-plist-into-an-nsarray.html) helps you with the plist.

Comment: could you give a link for a plist example? maybe this could be the solution. this way I would iterate through the plist data, which i can easily change, while the code stays the same right? besides i can focus the data and not changing the init methods of my objects.

Comment: @maver See the link I have added.

Answer (score 0):

```
   NSMutableArray* arrayOfActivity=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        Activity* activity1 = [[Activity alloc] init];
        [arrayOfActivity addObject:activity1];

    }

    for (Activity* act in arrayOfActivity) {
    // here you can implement all activity object one by one
    }
```

or you can do this on the first for like this

```
NSMutableArray* arrayOfActivity=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
         for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
             Activity* activity = [[Activity alloc] initwithTitle@"Bla" andScore:i];
             [arrayOfActivity addObject:activity1];

         }
```

Comment: Use the second for init directly the score or just put setter and getter on your object